# Opencv 4.1 conflicting older version on jetson nano

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, nvidia-jetson-nano

I installed opencv version 4.1 following [this guide](https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/buildOpenCV).
Looked like it completed fine, but when i test with:

```
import cv2 #this works
print(cv2.__version__) #but not this
```

I get an attributeerror: module 'cv2' has no attribute '**version**'

This is on the jetson nano with jetpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by removing opencv and do another build.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jetpack are you using? I suggest Jetpack 4.4. it comes with opencv 4.1. You don't need to build it from source.
Once you install Jetpack 4.4 Make sure you install dependencies for `python3 "cv2"`

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential make cmake cmake-curses-gui
$ sudo apt-get install -y git g++ pkg-config curl libfreetype6-dev
$ sudo apt-get install -y libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
$ sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-testresources python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install -U pip
$ cd ${HOME}/project/jetson_nano
$ ./install_protobuf-3.8.0.sh
$ sudo pip3 install numpy matplotlib
```

Test now.

Here is a full set up on Jetpack 4.2 including building opencv from source https://github.com/T-DevH/jetson-nano-tfdev (you won't need to do that with Jetpack 4.4)

Comment: thank you for answer. Fixed by removing opencv and do another build.
Does the opencv 4 that comes with jetpack 4.4 have cuda support included?